# php preg_match_all words starting with?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm pulling in a calendar from an external site with `file_get_contents`, so I can use jQuery .load on it.

In order to fix the relative path issues with this approach, I'm using 
preg_match_all.

So doing

`preg_match_all("/<a href='([^\"]*)'/iU", $string, $match);`

Gets me all the occurrences of `<a href = ''`
What I'm after are the just the links inside the single quotes.
Now each link starts with "?date" so I have `<a href='?date=4%2F9%2F2014&a'` etc.

How can I efficiently get the string between single quotes in all `<a href=` occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**`Dom parser`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the href from the `<a>` tag

```
<?php
$file =  "your.html";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($elements as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Comment: That is another way of doing it, and much better than how I started going about it. Thanks!